# Is there a more convenient way to start and debug an electron.net app?

Tags: electron

I'd love to start working with electron.net but the thing that keeps me from doing so is the way you have to start and debug your app. On the GitHub page it says you always have to run "dotnet electronize start" in the console (https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET#start-the-application) just to start the app and if you want to debug it you have to manually attach the process to visual studios debugger (https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET#debug ). Is there a way where I can run and debug the app just like any other asp.net app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the '.NET' part but for Electron development, I love [electron reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reload) ([github source](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload)) It reloads an electron app on source file changes.

Perhaps you can add in a console cmd to do what you need to get 'NET working.